# Калькулятор с использование фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment

Набрёл на интересный пример с использованием фрагментов 
[ссылка](http://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-create-a-simple-android-calculator-application/)
Но увы возникли трудности в файле MainActivity.java при объявлении самого фрагмента(а именно как связать активити и фрагмент)
Пробовал следующее

```
public SimpleCalculatorFragment fragment1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragment1 = (SimpleCalculatorFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
```

В чём моя проблема, подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы абсолютно не понимаете принципы работы фрагментов и активити.

Советую почитать [всё что касается фрагментов](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php) и желательно несколько раз.

Все ответы на ваши вопросы найдутся здесь. Код, который вы привели - лишь вырванный кусок из контекста.

Comment: спасибо за инфу, она для меня не новая, но увы не дотягиваю видимо, пробую и так и этак и ждал более полезного совета, чем просто ссылку на теорию.

Comment: у вас ссылка оформлена не правильно:" Набрёл на интересный пример с использованием фрагментов [Ссылка][1] " если присмотритесь внимательнее.

И если не додумывать - то фрагмент по айди вы уже нашли. К сожалению, не представляю, что за ссылку вы пытались прикрепить, что-бы верно понять вашу проблему.

Comment: да, спасибо, откорректировал пост.
Посмотрите пожалуйста, если нетрудно.
До сих пор мучаюсь с этой проблемой(

Comment: Предлагаю пойти следующим путём: скажите конкретно что вы хотите от фрагмента и связи с активити.

Например можете использовать `getActivity();` и вызвать нужный вам метод.

С другой стороны ваш код должен работать, может, он выдает определенные ошибки\стек?

тот же пример с сайта указанного в ссылке:

`CatFragment catFragment = (CatFragment)             getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentCat);
        catFragment.sayMeow("Жрать!"); ` - работает

Comment: Хочу запустить калькулятор, который опубликован на сайте.
Другими словами правильно описать фрагменты в активности, т.к. именно в этом пожалуй причина. Открывается окно с самим калькулятором, но он не обрабатывает нажатия и соответственно не делает никаких расчётов...

Comment: постарался внимательно прочесть сайт по ссылке, наткнулся на вот этот блок от автора: **Now, lets moves over to our project Activity file. In this file, we will get the handle for all of our view components. The class will implement implements View.OnClickListener and we will override the View onClick method.** 

Попробуйте найти другой пример, поскольку я думаю он ошибся - вместо активити он выложил фрагмент. 

К тому же в комментах к нему люди спрашивают код. 

Потому выложил он явно не всё.

Comment: Спасибо большое
Но видимо на завтра я пропал, потому как сдавать именно завтра...(
А почти везде примеры калькуляторов только с активити((

Comment: Чем вам не угодил активити, и необходимо использовать именно фрагмент?

Comment: Именно
Задание было создать калькулятор, который будет использовать фрагмент

Comment: Что же вы так на последнего момента дотянули

Comment: Пытался делать сам) ну ничё, разберемся, спасибо за диалог